# Изменить дату в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, циклы, dataframe, datetime

У меня есть DataFrame:

```
Year     Month
2017     01
2017     02
2018     03
2018     04
2017     05
```

Мне нужно изменить год только там, где месяцы 01,02,03

Я создала функцию:

```
def Year_Fin (row):
if (row['Month'] == '01') or (row['Month'] == '02') or (row['Month'] == '03'):
    (row['Year'] + 1)

return row
```

И передаю ее в .apply()

```
data = data.apply(Year_Fin)
```

Не работает!
Кто знает, как написать правильно функцию, чтобы она работала?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [127]: df
Out[127]:
   Year Month
0  2017    01
1  2017    02
2  2018    03
3  2018    04
4  2017    05

In [128]: df = df.assign(Year=pd.to_numeric(df['Year'], errors='coerce'))

In [129]: df.loc[df['Month'].isin(['01','02','03']), 'Year'] += 1

In [130]: df
Out[130]:
   Year Month
0  2018    01
1  2018    02
2  2019    03
3  2018    04
4  2017    05
```